# What's the difference in these two function calls exactly?

Tags: javascript, function, invoke

Why can I call this function, without a return statement in it:

```
function addSmt1( num1,  num2){

    console.log(num1+num2)
    
    }

addSmt1(2,3)
```

like this?

But can't do it here:

```
function addSmt( num1,  num2){

    return num1+num2;

}

let x = addSmt(2,4)
console.log(x)
```

Why do I have to put the function call of a function with a return inside a variable to call it?

Btw do I stress too much on such 'minor' details?

Comment: console.log() is just an output statement for user reference  therefore it doesn't return any value....so if you want to just display the sum you can use method 1 but instead if you want to assign the result in a variable to use it in some other computation then you need to go with the second method

Answer (score 0):

You can call function with a return inside without putting the call into a variable. But if you don't, you won't be able to access the data returned by the function

Answer (score 0):

**Return Statements**
When you put a `return` statement in a function, you are telling the interpreter that you can assign a variable to the return value of a function. This means that when assigning the variable, **all** code inside the function is run before the return value is assigned. Let's say you had a function like this:

```js
function multiplySums(a, b, c, d) {
alert('Running!')
return (a+b)*(c+d);
}
```

When you assigned a variable say `product` to `multiplySums(5, 4, 6, 7)`, you are basically telling the interpreter to run all code inside `multiplySums`, then return the value, which in this case is `117`.
Now, what if multiplySums was modified like this?

```js
function multiplySums(a, b, c, d) {
alert('Running!')
alert((a+b)*(c+d));
}
```

Remember that functions that do not return, are called **voids**. They do implicitly return a value, and that is `undefined` (similar to Python where voids return `None`.) So, here you would be assigning a variable to undefined.
What if you just called the function with no assignment? Let's call `multiplySumsReturn` the function which returns and `multiplySumsVoid` the one that doesn't:

- `multiplySumsVoid(1, 2, 3, 4)` alerts the calculation.
- `multiplySumsReturn(1, 2, 3, 4)` alerts `Running!` but will not alert the calculation unless you are running this directly in the console, in which case it implicitly logs the return value to the console.
- `let product = multiplySumsVoid(1, 2, 3, 4)` is basically declaring a variable without assignment seeing as the void returns `undefined`. Yes, you are alerting the calculation, but you cannot perform any operations with this variable.
- `let product = multiplySumsReturn(1, 2, 3, 4)` will assign the variable to the return value, which is the reason why the `return` keyword exists! To be able to reuse calculations and values.

Hope it makes sense, and sorry for the long answer.